# Disable fade in and out animation of KivyMD toast

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, kivymd

I am trying to create an app and use a toast to show a message, but when the toast is displayed the background changes to a darker color (see image below). Is there a way to disable this, so just the toast is displayed without a fade animation.

Note that I installed kivy with pip, I typed: `pip install https://github.com/kivy/kivy/archive/master.zip`

[image]

```
from kivy.lang import Builder

from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.toast import toast

KV = '''
BoxLayout:
    orientation:'vertical'

    MDToolbar:
        id: toolbar
        title: 'Test Toast'
        md_bg_color: app.theme_cls.primary_color
        left_action_items: [['menu', lambda x: '']]

    FloatLayout:

        MDRaisedButton:
            text: 'TEST KIVY TOAST'
            on_release: app.show_toast()
            pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}

'''

class Test(MDApp):
    def show_toast(self):
        '''Displays a toast on the screen.'''

        toast('Test Kivy Toast')

    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)

Test().run()
```

Comment: I have tried your code and I am not getting any fade animation. Which  version of KivyMD are you using?

Comment: @Fadi Abu Raide I am using KivyMD version: 0.104.2.dev0

Comment: My version is  kivymd 0.104.1. Try ```pip uninstall kivymd```. Then ```pip install kivymd==0.104.1``` .

Answer (score 0):

The fade in and fade out are hard wired characteristics of `Toast`. There is no way to change that. However, you can create your own version of that class by extending `Toast`, something like this:

```
from kivymd.toast.kivytoast.kivytoast import Toast


class MyToast(Toast):

    def fade_in(self):
        self.label_toast.opacity = 1
        self.opacity = 1

    def fade_out(self, interval):
        self.label_toast.opacity = 0
        self.opacity = 0
        self.dismiss()
```

I haven't tested this code, but this should give you the idea of how to approach this. Also, note that if this app ends up as an Android App, then the above code will not be used, but the actual Android Toast would be used.